# Extract Jenkins pipeline from job when it's only defined in the Jenkins GUI

Tags: jenkins

I have any Jenkins jobs that are written directly into Jenkins pipeline script and not directly in the SCM as is best practice.

I have been tasked with grabbing these scripts and firstly creating a backup of them.

My preference is to script the collection using python something like the below:

```
from utils.args import parse_arguments
from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins

args = parse_arguments()

url = "http://jmaster:8080/"

master = Jenkins(url, username=args.username, password=args.password)

for job in master.get_jobs():
    print(job[0])
    if (job[1]._data["_class"] == "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob"):
        print "doing work"
```

However this is where I get stuck as I cannot see the pipeline script is exposed ? Is it even exposed as a JSON parameter that I have access to ?

I've tried looking at the jenkins api data structure no luck.
I have tried to use the rest api directly in a browser but I couldn't find the right part.

Does anyone know if this is possible or am I just chasing a dream ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried grabbing job's config.xml files? (from like http://jmaster:8080/jobs/myjob/config.xml)

There it looks like this:

```
<definition class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowDefinition" plugin="workflow-cps@2.59">
<script>node { echo 'Hello World' }</script>
<sandbox>false</sandbox>
</definition>
```

Or maybe you can get the CpsFlowDefinition with groovy in your original code...